# A hint for end of ASCII data in a binary file

Tags: shell, unix, binary, ascii, binaryfiles

I'm developing a software that stores its data in a binary file format. However, as a courtesy to innocent shell users that might `cat` to inspect the contents of such a file, I'm thinking of having an ASCII-compatible "magic string" in the start of the file that tells the name and the version of the binary format.

I'm thinking of having at least ten rows (`\n`) in the message so that `head` by default settings doesn't hit the binary part.

Now, I wonder if there is any control character or escape code that would hint to the shell that the following content isn't interpretable as printable text, and should be just ignored? I tried `0x00` (the null byte) and `0x04` (ctrl-D) but they seem to be just ignored when `cat`ting the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cat regards a file as text. There is no way you can trigger an end-of-file, since EOF is not actually any character.

The other way around works of course; specifying a format that only start reading binary format from a certain character on.